# firebase.firestore().collection().where(_, _, *) 'value' is invalid. 'not-in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

firebase.firestore().collection().where(_, _, *) 'value' is invalid. 'not-in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.

```
 unlanguages = firestore()
            .collection("users")
    -->     .where("id", "not-in", [...passedUserIds, ...smashesUserIds])
            .onSnapshot(async querySnapshot => {
                if (querySnapshot?.docs?.length > 0) {
                    let dondur2 = await querySnapshot?.docs
                        .filter((doc) => doc.id != user.uid)
                        .filter((doc) => doc._data.gender != loggedInProfile.gender)
                        .filter((doc) => doc._data.age <= `${value[1]}`)
                        .filter((doc) => doc._data.age >= `${value[0]}`)
                        .filter((doc) =>
                            doc._data.languages[0] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[1] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[2] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[3] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[4] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[5] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[6] == languages ||
                            doc._data.languages[7] == languages
                        )
                        .map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
                    setProfiles(dondur2)

                }
            })
```

so at where there is a problem ' ids ' more than 10 and how do i solve it? I looked other opened questions but this not working for me

Answer (score 2):

> Where there is a problem ' ids ' more than 10?

It's on this line:

```
.where("id", "not-in", [...passedUserIds, ...smashesUserIds])
```

You very most probably have more than 10 elements in the `[...passedUserIds, ...smashesUserIds]` array.

> How do i solve it?

**This is a Firestore limitation.** The only ways to circumvent it are either to adapt your data model or to find a way to minimize the number of elements in the array. Without seeing some real examples of your data it's difficult to advise you further.

Comment: I don't want the user to see people they've liked and passed and how can i solve? This app is friendship app and How do they do it in other apps?

Comment: Can you tag all the other users? For example by having a boolean field which ID is the id of the user and value is true? To give a more precise answer/tip I need much more details on the logical data model.

Comment: my firebase data model about
"sei nicht schüchtern"
age
"26"
displayName
"Leonie"
gender
"Female"
id
"1aOqsq8ZTYwGTvWGEHav"
languages
(array)
0
"Deutsch"
photoURL
"https: